# JavaScript $.GET not passing through

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am building a very simple chat application, nothing too fancy just a way for multiple users to chat at once.

The problem I am having is that whilst I can read and display messages from the database, no new messages will get inserted.

I am using JavaScript to pass a `$.Get` with the message and the username. I have checked the console and there is no errors showing but I have an `undefined index: text` and `undefined index: username` when I use POSTMAN to test.

Can anyone help push me in the right direction to solve this?

**chat.php**

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <p id='chat-user'> </p>
            <div id='chat-area'></div>
            <form id='send-message-area'>
                <textarea name="the-textarea" id="the-textarea" maxlength="150" placeholder="Start Typing..."autofocus></textarea>              
            </form>
            <button id='chatSend' class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Post New Message</button>
            <div id="the-count">
                <span id="current">0</span>
                <span id="maximum">/ 150</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
var name = prompt("Enter your name:", "Guest");
            if (!name || name === ' ') {
                name = "Guest";
            }
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("chat-user").innerHTML = "Your are: " + name;
            };

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var chatInterval = 250;                       
                var $chatOutput = $("#chat-area");
                var $chatInput = $("#the-textarea");
                var $chatSend = $("#chatSend");

                function sendMessage() {               
                    var chatInputString = $chatInput.val();

                    $.GET("testProcess.php", {
                        username: name,
                        text: chatInputString
                    });


                    retrieveMessages();
                }
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ("connection.php");


$username = substr($_GET["username"], 0, 32);
$text = substr($_GET["text"], 0, 150);

$nameEscaped = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username)); 
$textEscaped = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $text)); 
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$insertMessage = "INSERT INTO message (messageID, messageBody, timeSent, nickname, sent) VALUES ('', '$textEscaped', '$timestamp', '$nameEscaped')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertMessage);
```

[image: Messages being displayed]

[image: Error Messages]

Comment: I see `post` and see you using `get`

Comment: Hi @epascarello, that was an error, I entered ````post```` incorrectly, edited question to reflect. Issue still remains!

Comment: this doesn't really have anything to do with the question at hand, but i would recommend that you use a websocket connection for your data transmission. Not Get/Post.

Comment: You're inserting an empty string as messageID. Is it a PK? What type is it?

Comment: @Yidna, yes ````messageID````, is the primary key of my ````message```` table.

Comment: Primary keys can't be duplicates. If you're repeatedly trying to insert the same value (in this case empty string) as the PK, it'll just fail.

Comment: You really should not be using a GET to update a database

Comment: The primary key column should be autoincrement, and be omitted in the insert query. What parameters do you use when checking the process.php with postman?

Comment: Got sorted guys, was a Query error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive so `$.GET` most certainly throws an error (at least if `$` refers to jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Your postman request is wrong as shown in the picture
you are passing the param GET with the value send but in your php script you have $_GET["username"] and $_GET["text"] the method GET is already set in the left side of the url in the picture so you dont need to send it what you want to send is the param username and text so the url would look like this

```
http://xxxxxxx/testProcess.php?username=Guest&text=test
```

as for your javascript code the jquery method for get is $.get and not $.GET and you are missing a way to handle the submit of the form because your submit button is outside of the form so a correct way to this would be

```
    var name = prompt("Enter your name:", "Guest");
    if (!name || name === ' ') {
      name = "Guest";
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("chat-user").innerHTML = "Your are: " + name;
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var chatInterval = 250;
    var $chatOutput = $("#chat-area");
    var $chatInput = $("#the-textarea");
    var $chatSend = $("#chatSend");

    //intercepting the submit event to call the sendMessage function
    $("#send-message-area").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      sendMessage()
    })

    function sendMessage() {
      var chatInputString = $chatInput.val();
      $.get("testProcess.php", {
        username: name,
        text: chatInputString
      });


      retrieveMessages();
    }
  })
```